# command line program to list layers in a DXF/DWG file

Tags: autocad, cad, command-line-tool

I have a CAD file and I'd like to do some scripting with it and was hoping for a little software program that could just give me a list of the layers.  I tried (on mac and windows) to get CAD::Drawing from cpan working (perl) to no avail.

Could somebody point me to either a library (more or less any language is fine) or a software program that will allow me to accomplish this.  Platform doesn't matter I have access to Linux mac and pc.

Thanks

Comment: If you're working with AutoCAD, it would make sense to use the built-in AutoLisp capabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For standalone applications, the two most common DWG libraries are [Teigha](http://www.opendesign.com/the_oda_platform/Teigha) and [RealDWG](http://www.autodesk.com/realdwg). DXF files are text files that can be parsed fairly easily without any special libraries.